# Vector Table for Bootloader

Tags: microcontroller, bootloader

Most, if not all, microcontrollers have a vector table for all the exceptions that are encountered when the program is running. I am quite confused as to whether the bootloader also has its own vector table for executing the reset handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bootloader is just a program there is no magic there, as with any other program if it needs a vector table the programmers create a vector table.  Certainly if it needs to run from reset then it must conform to the hardware/processor rules for that.  The processor nor any of the other logic has any way to know that that collection of bits, that collection of instructions is a bootloader or not.  It just runs it.

I assume you are talking about the many, but not all, flavors/brands of microcontrollers that have bootloaders programmed at the factory?

Within an mcu there is a processor core with a memory bus.  The many items in the chip, ram, flash, gpio, spi, timer, uart, adc, etc all live on that bus like having more than one house on a particular street.  Each of these items on the processor bus have address decoders looking for their address on the bus to know when to take or provide data/information.  The application flash and bootloader rom are no different, not special.  As easy as it is to do in software it is as easy in hardware to have some sort of if-then-else that allows the application flash to answer the processor at the vector table addresses, that flag that drives the then or else cases can be an input pin to the part.  Tie the pin high and hit the reset and the part boots from one memory, tie the pin low hit the reset and the part boots from the other.   There are other solutions out there that are perhaps not driven by an input pin to the part but by the bootloader software.

Sometimes the processor core itself has a signal that the chip vendor drives however it wants, that within the processor core it does an if-then else, perhaps the then case is 0x00000000 is where it looks for the vector table, and the else case 0xFFFF0000.

At the end of the day though a bootloader is just another program, written by someone for this chip, no different than the program you write for the chip other than the fact that if it is a factory programmed rom bootloader then the programmer for that bootloader might have additional information/documentation for that part that we dont have.   But being a bootloader is not magic it is just a program, a collection of instructions.  our application can be a bootloader as well, with several possible different applicaitons based on what our bootloader finds, their bootloader can boot our bootloader which then chooses from several applications and runs one of them.  All within one part...

Comment: Note this is generally documented for each part or family.  What part/family were you interested in?  What part of the documentation did you not understand?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I will get back to you in some time with more details.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a bootloader that has been ported between a number of different embedded processors used within comms products (MSP430, AVR32, DSP56300).  This loader had quite limited functional requirements

1. Hardware initialisation.
2. Validate the main code image using a checksum or cryptographic signature.
3. Transfer of control to the main application if the validation passes.
4. Provide a minimal command interface over a serial port to allow for firmware update.
5. Reentry point to allow the main application to trigger a new firmware load.

This transfer of operation between the two programmes held in non volatile memory on the same processor meant that I had to provide a re-direction of the interrupt functions between the two completely separate applications.  The Interrupt table for the MSP430 is held in FLASH and so cannot be modified easily.  It also holds the reset vector that must always point to the start of the bootloader code so erasing and rewriting this area runs the risk of completely bricking the unit.

The solution in this case was to have an interrupt service routine in the bootloader that redirected through a vector table located at a fixed location within the application memory space.  Using this method added one indirect jump instruction to each interrupt handler resulting in a minimal extra processor load for each interrupt that is processed.  The bootloader was written to not use any interrupts relying on polling the serial port status for all of the communications.  If the bootloader needed to use interrupts then the vector table can be moved to RAM and initialised by the bootloader or application as required. (My processor did not have enough RAM to allow this)

There was a simple data structure at a fixed location in the main application code that contained entries for each possible interrupt/exception and the start address of the application code (you could consider this as the application code reset vector).  As long as the application provided this data structure in flash and correctly populated it could be compiled and build completely separately as if it was the only application on the processor.